# Django : count foreign key and display

Tags: django, count, foreign-keys

Suppose I have two table in my database,

1. **booktable** which have 3 attributes (**id**, **book_name**, **writer_id**(foreignkey))
2. **writertable** which have 2 attributes (**id**, **writer_name**)

I want to display writer name and **how many books have that writer** by calculate **booktable**

**book table**

```
---------------------------------------
|   id   |   book_name   |  writer_id |
|-------------------------------------|
|    1   |   abc         |      2     |
|    2   |   bcd         |      1     |
|    3   |   efg         |      1     |
|    4   |   htj         |      2     |
|    5   |   klm         |      1     |
|    6   |   nop         |      3     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**Writer table**

```
----------------------------
|   id   |   writer_name   |
|---------------------------
|    1   |     xyz         |
|    2   |     bcb         |
|    3   |     eld         |
|    4   |     ccb         |
|---------------------------

so, 
  id 1 = 3 books
     2 = 3 books
     4 = 0 books
```

How can I display in html template. Here is my code,

**models.py**

```
class book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(writer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class writer(models.Model):
    writer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.writer_name
```

**view.py**

```
def getwriters(request):
    wrt = writer.objects.all()
    return render(request, "writers.html", {"wrt":wrt})
```

**writers.html**

```
    {% for p in wrt %}  
        <tr>
            <td>{{ p.writer_name }}</td>
            <td>{{**Should display how many books have this writer**}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **annotate** the queryset with:

```
def getwriters(request):
    wrt = writer.objects.annotate(
        numbooks=Count('book')
    )
    return render(request, "writers.html", {"wrt":wrt})
```

This will add to *every* `writer` object an extra attribute `numbook` that contains the number of *related* books (so in this case books written by that writer).

You can then render it as:

```
{% for p in wrt %}  
    <tr>
        <td>{{ p.writer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.numbooks }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
book.objects.filter(writer_pk=1).count()
```

This will return count of all books with writer whose pk is 1

Comment: I have the idea that we need to obtain the number of books written for *every* writer. As a result, if the number of writers is rather large, this would be rather inefficient, since it results in *N+1 fetches*.